# Unable to LIMIT the query

Tags: php, mysqli

I am  unable to LIMIT the no. of query runs.

My code goes as:

```
 <?php
      $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM smf_log_digest WHERE note_type = 'topic'";
      $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
      if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
          $number = $row2["id_msg"];
          $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM smf_messages WHERE id_msg = $number LIMIT 10";
          $result3 = $conn->query($sql3);
          if ($result3->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc()) {
              echo $row3["subject"];
            }
          } else {
            echo "";
          }
        }
      } else {
        echo "";
      }
      $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Comment: <?php 
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM 'smf_log_digest' WHERE note_type = 'topic'";
.
.
.
$conn->close();
?>
open and close php only once

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: it says `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: which line for the error?

Comment: you're not checking for the real error. We also don't know if you did connect and using the same api.

Answer (score 0):

$row2 is a Array so ...

$topic = $row2 **[** "id_msg" **]**;